# jQuery Tools - Vertical Scroller One Item Too Long

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I asked this over at the jQuery Tools official forum last week, but it's definitely not as active as stackoverflow, so thought I would ask over here as well.

On our project detail pages, we're dynamically loading content in that uses a vertical scroller to navigate through. Problem is that the height of the vertical scroller always seems to be one item too tall. I cannot find any way to affect this programmatically.

If I set it circular to true, it seems to have the correct height, but we don't want it to be continuous/circular.

Example here:
http://www.centerline.net/projects/detail/?p=21

Unminified JS is here:
http://www.centerline.net/lib/js/site-unmin.js

Any ideas?

Here's the view of what it should look like when scrolled to the last item (down arrow disappears, and does not allow a blank area below the last thumbnail.
[image: Correct Vertical Scroller Stop Point]

Comment: Please clarify how it should look, photoshopped screenshot would be good ;-)

Comment: @Gary Green Design looks fine. But when you hit the down arrows to the right of the main image or video, it scrolls too far by one item. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution above looked like it would have worked, but also found a solution here:

http://www.jasoncarr.com/technology/jquery-tools-scrollable-stop-scrolling-past-the-end

Actual code for my site was as such:

```
$(function() {
  // Initialize the Scrollable control
  $(".scroll").scrollable({vertical:true, mousewheel:true, keyboard:true });

  // Get the Scrollable control
  var scrollable = jQuery(".scroll").data("scrollable");

  // Set to the number of visible items
  var size = 2;
  // Handle the Scrollable control's onSeek event
  scrollable.onSeek(function(event, index) {

    // Check to see if we're at the end
    if (this.getIndex() >= this.getSize() - size) {

      // Disable the Next link
      jQuery("a.next").addClass("disabled");
    }
  });

  // Handle the Scrollable control's onBeforeSeek event
  scrollable.onBeforeSeek(function(event, index) {

    // Check to see if we're at the end
    if (this.getIndex() >= this.getSize() - size) {

      // Check to see if we're trying to move forward
      if (index > this.getIndex()) {
        // Cancel navigation
        return false;
      }
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the number of divs in the .items container should be divisible by the number of items you want to show at a time. So you have 3 divs but you are showing 2 items at a time. That is why the scrollable plugin malfunctions. 
You can either open the nonminified source and change it a little bit which shoudn't be very difficult.

Or much simpler solution would be to either add a new div and make it 4 to 2.

Or Drop the number of items you show at a time to 1 and increase the height of your divs.

Using another plugin may work too.

Hope it helps

Comment: @omekirk: If I have 4 divs, showing 2 at a time, it still malfunctions: http://www.centerline.net/projects/detail/?p=104 
or are you saying that because it scrolls by one item, but has 2 viewable at any given time the problem? If that's the case, how would I adjust it to scroll two at a time?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that jQuery tools srolls all images. And after the last images there just is some empty space.

Try to add this to the scrollable constructor

```
$('.scroll').scrollable({
   onBeforeSeek: function(e, index) {
        if (index == $('.items').size()) {
            return false;
        }
    },
    onSeek: function(e, index) {
        if (index == $('.items').size()-1) {
            $('.next').hide(0);
        } else {
            if ($('.next').is(':hidden')) {
                $('.next').show();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

OR

```
api = $('.scroll').scrollable({
   //your setup code
});

api.onBeforeSeek: function(e, index) {
        if (index == this.getSize()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
 api.onSeek: function(e, index) {
        if (index == this.getSize()-1) {
            $('.next').hide(0);
        } else {
            if ($('.next').is(':hidden')) {
                $('.next').show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Disclaimer: Im no expert. I have not tested this. Your code is minified, can't see it clearly. I hardly use jQuery tools. But I think this would be the way to go.

Comment: My original line to fire it was `$(".scroll").scrollable({vertical:true, mousewheel:true, keyboard:true });`
Adding your code and re-inserting `vertical:true, mousewheel:true, keyboard:true` in before the `onBeforeSeek` doesn't seem to work. (No longer scrolls and throws an error of "$(this).getIndex is not a function" when clicking on the down arrow.

Comment: try it like this. (see edit). again im no expert. if you build that site you must have some idea what you doing and modifying my suggestion shoudnt be to hard. take a look at the documentation http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/ specifically the events part

Comment: I'm no expert either, hence my questions on here. :)
Your solution and the documentation on flowplayer.org's site seem to make sense if I could figure out the syntax.

Comment: In plain english: You want to prevent the last scroll. and want to hide the scroll button. onBeforeSeek is triggered BEFORE the scroll happens. the index parameter is the index of the item it will scroll to. so. if that is the last item (thats why you need to know the total amount of items) return false so it stops executing. the onSeek function is fired AFTER the scroll happened. it checks it index to the total items. if it is the one before last. Hide the next button. if it's not. Show the next button if its hidden (in case the person scrolls up) jQuery tools itself is weird in its api imo:)